# Angular > 12: avoiding devDependencies for prod build

Tags: angular, npm, production

Developers in the 2020s live in a world of vulnerabilities and lots of dependencies. My mantra has been *"If it isn't used in production, it should not be in production"* for a while. I try to implement this in all aspects of my development, but I am having issues with an angular application:

During my CI/CD pipeline I execute the following commands:

- During the **staging** step:

  - `npm ci` - installing the dependencies
  - `ng build` - building the angular application for testing
- During the **testing** step:

  - `npm run test-headless` (translates to `ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless`) - perform headless testing
- During **Prod Deploy** step: (different node)

  - `npm ci --omit=dev` - install w/o devDependencies
  - `ng build --base-href "https://${SITE_FQDN}"`

The issue is that the final `ng build` step fails on the postinstall phase since `ngcc` is not installed (because it is a devDependency)

Searching around there are many questions about [production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083391/building-angular-for-production-without-installing-devdependencies) versions and [devDependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67419589/when-exactly-are-devdependencies-included-into-the-angular-build) [..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801451/why-arent-all-angular-packages-declared-as-devdependencies) even articles about [there no longer being a dev build](https://www.beyondjava.net/angular12-development-build)

I am brimming with questions at this point, feeling that I have no control or overview of what I am putting in production, but the main question is:

How do I ensure that what I produce with `ng build` is production ready without all the development bindings and devDependencies?